# Meteor: ReferenceError: require is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, npm

I have installed `meteorhacks:npm` and defined apn in packages.json `{"apn": "1.6.2"}`. However, I get an error `ReferenceError: require is not defined` when I run the following code:

```
var apn = Npm.require('apn'),
    path = Npm.require('path'),
    apnOptions = Meteor.settings.apnOptions || {},
    alertSound = apnOptions.sound || "alert.aiff",
    apnConnection

// default apn connection options
apnOptions = _.extend({
  cert: path.join(appRootPath, "private", "cert.pem"),
  key: path.join(appRootPath, "private", "key.pem"),
}, apnOptions)
apnConnection = new apn.Connection(apnOptions)
```

The full error message:

```
W20150116-23:30:51.097(2)? (STDERR)           
W20150116-23:30:51.100(2)? (STDERR) /Users/Mika/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.38.zbazwc++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:173
W20150116-23:30:51.101(2)? (STDERR)                         throw(ex);
W20150116-23:30:51.101(2)? (STDERR)                               ^
W20150116-23:30:51.101(2)? (STDERR) ReferenceError: require is not defined
W20150116-23:30:51.102(2)? (STDERR)     at app/node_modules/apn/lib/connection.js:1:49
W20150116-23:30:51.102(2)? (STDERR)     at app/node_modules/apn/lib/connection.js:774:3
W20150116-23:30:51.106(2)? (STDERR)     at /Users/Mika/Devaus/meteor/flashcards/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:175:10
W20150116-23:30:51.107(2)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20150116-23:30:51.107(2)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/Mika/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.38.zbazwc++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
W20150116-23:30:51.107(2)? (STDERR)     at /Users/Mika/Devaus/meteor/flashcards/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:86:5
```

My repo: https://github.com/mvaisanen/flashcards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Meteor.npmRequire` insted of `Npm.require` for packages loaded via [meteorhacks:npm](https://github.com/meteorhacks/npm). For example:

```
var apn = Meteor.npmRequire('apn');
var path = Npm.require('path');
```

Also note that requiring an npm package will only work on the server, so make sure that code is in your `/server` directory or guarded by `Meteor.isServer`.

Comment: Can you add the code to a branch in your repo so I can see the whole thing?

Comment: Sure. I just made an commit. I actually just got the problem solved but I still don't know how get push notifications working. Nothing happens when I build and run it on xcode. It doesn't even ask to enable push notifications.

Comment: It seems like you are trying to use `apn` from the client however, like I said in the answer, you can only use npm packages on the server. You need to either use a client library for push notifications (I don't know if that exists), of you need to access the `apn` functionality via a method. See the [example](https://github.com/meteorhacks/npm#example-on-using-npm-module-inside-a-meteor-method) from the docs.